# Create unique hyperlink for all the values in the cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet report of Jira's that I would like to update and add a hyperlink.
Each cell can contain multiple Jira numbers.

I want to generate a unique hyperlink for each of the Jira numbers in the cell.

---

**Jira number**: FAP-137076

**Jira link format**: https://domain.atlassian.net/browse/FAP-137076

**Jira sample cell content**: FAP-137076,FAP-125251,FAP-125547,FAP-125550,FAP-126136,FAP-126828,FAP-127351,FAP-132693,SMART-46475,HELL-2666

---

**Current data example:**:

[image]

**Desired outcome:**

[image]

I have the following code, but I am stuck on the first Jira number link generating step with the following error.

```
Exception: Illegal argument.
buildRichLink   @ Code.gs:22
```

How can I write a loop to go through each cell and create unique hyperlinks for each Jira?

**Current code:**

```
function buildJiraLink() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")

  var LABEL = "JIRA#"

  const casesData = ws.getDataRange().getValues()
  var indexNo = casesData[0].indexOf(LABEL)

  for (var i = 1; i < casesData.length; i++) { // offset the header row
    var cellValue = casesData[i][indexNo]
    var cellArray = cellValue.split(",")
    var startRow = i+1

    var offsetValue = 0
    for (var c=0; c < cellArray.length; c++) {
      var tempCell = cellArray[c]   
      var RichTextValue = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
        .setText(tempCell + ", ")
        .setLinkUrl(offsetValue,tempCell.length, "https://domain.atlassian.net/browse/" + tempCell)
        .build()

      ws.getRange(startRow,indexNo+1).setRichTextValue(RichTextValue)
      offsetValue = offsetValue + tempCell.length

      Logger.log(c + 1 + " " + tempCell)
      
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, the object of RichTextValue is created to one hyperlink. From your showing expected situation, it is required to build the object of RichTextValue including multiple hyperlinks.
- From your showing your expected result, it seems that you wanted to change the delimiter from `,` to `,` . In this case, it is also required to consider it.
- And, in your script, `setRichTextValue` is used in a loop. In this case, the process cost will become high.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function buildJiraLink() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var LABEL = "JIRA#";
  const casesData = ws.getDataRange().getValues();
  var indexNo = casesData[0].indexOf(LABEL);

  // I modified below script.
  const delimiter = ", "; // Please set your expected delimiter of outout situation.
  const range = ws.getRange(2, indexNo + 1, ws.getLastRow() - 1);
  const richTextValues = range.getRichTextValues().map(([r]) => {
    const ar = r.getText().split(",").map(e => e.trim());
    const copied = r.copy().setText(ar.join(delimiter));
    let start = 0;
    ar.forEach((e, i) => {
      copied.setLinkUrl(start, start + e.length, `https://domain.atlassian.net/browse/${e}`);
      start += e.length + delimiter.length;
    });
    return [copied.build()];
  });
  range.setRichTextValues(richTextValues);
}
```

#### Testing:

When this modified script is run, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### References:

- [setRichTextValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setrichtextvaluesvalues)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

### Added:

About your following new issue, in which you would like to:

> modify this code to skip if one of the cells is empty? I am getting an error Exception: Illegal argument as soon as first cell is empty.

From your showing sample image, I believed that the column has all values. So, for your new issue, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

```js
function buildJiraLink() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var LABEL = "JIRA#";
  const casesData = ws.getDataRange().getValues();
  var indexNo = casesData[0].indexOf(LABEL);

  // I modified below script.
  const delimiter = ", "; // Please set your expected delimiter of outout situation.
  const range = ws.getRange(2, indexNo + 1, ws.getLastRow() - 1);
  const richTextValues = range.getRichTextValues().map(([r]) => {
    const text = r.getText();
    if (text) {
      const ar = r.getText().split(",").map(e => e.trim());
      const copied = r.copy().setText(ar.join(delimiter));
      let start = 0;
      ar.forEach((e, i) => {
        copied.setLinkUrl(start, start + e.length, `https://domain.atlassian.net/browse/${e}`);
        start += e.length + delimiter.length;
      });
      return [copied.build()];
    }
    return [r];
  });
  range.setRichTextValues(richTextValues);
}
```

Comment: your code works like a charm! Can you please help me understand the `${e}` of your code? What is this method called, I would like to learn more about it. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @Omen Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `Can you please help me understand the ${e} of your code?`, this is the template literals. I think that this document might be useful. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Can you please help modify this code to skip if one of the cells is empty? I am getting an error `Exception: Illegal argument` as soon as first cell is empty. Thank you

Comment: @Omen About your new issue of `Can you please help modify this code to skip if one of the cells is empty? I am getting an error Exception: Illegal argument as soon as first cell is empty. Thank you`, from your showing sample image, I believed that the column has all values. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. So, for your new issue, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: I have added also a small `IF` to check if the column "JIRA#" exists and now it's bulletproof code, all thanks to you!

Comment: @halfer Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I think that my English skill is very poor. So, when I read a question, I'm always worried whether my understanding is correct. So, first, I try to correctly understand the question. When I could correctly understand the question, I think that I will be able to show the direction including your comment. But, now, I still have to deeply apologize for my poor English skill. I have to study English more.

Comment: I don't agree with that, but that is not the main point. I was noting that you seem to be willing to undertake a large amount of work that question authors should be doing themselves. Your interlocutor here asks "please help me with" in the comments, but they don't want to be _assisted_ - they want you to do all of their work, from start to finish. I wonder, might they never learn if they never write any code for themselves?

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the creation of the `RichTextValue` outside of the loop and only call `setLinkUrl` inside the loop. Something like:

```
var richTextValueBuilder = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(cellArray.join(", "));
for (var c=0; c < cellArray.length; c++) {
  var tempCell = cellArray[c]   
  
  richTextValueBuilder.setLinkUrl(offsetValue,tempCell.length, "https://domain.atlassian.net/browse/" + tempCell);

  offsetValue = offsetValue + tempCell.length + 2 //account for comma and space
  Logger.log(c + 1 + " " + tempCell)
}
ws.getRange(startRow,indexNo+1).
    setRichTextValue(richTextValueBuilder.build())
```